# set current date on datepicker AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

So, a modal opens up when I click on a button on m md-card to select a date. This is the code for it:

```
      <!-- Modal -->
 <md-dialog aria-label="Date Picker">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-header -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <md-input-container flex> <input type="date"
                ng-model="startDateL"> </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container flex> <label>{{}}</label> <input
                type="date" ng-model="endDateL"> </md-input-container>
            <!-- /.modal-search-box -->

            <md-button ng-click="setDate()" class="md-primary">Update
            Date</md-button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-body -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
</md-dialog>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

and this is the code for my controller to select a date

```
function datePickerController($scope, $mdDialog, $rootScope, datePickerFactory, $filter){
    console.log("suntem in date picker sel");
    $scope.startDateL = new Date($rootScope.startDate);
    $scope.endDateL = new Date($rootScope.endDate);

    $scope.close = function() {
        $mdDialog.hide();
        console.log("closing");
    }



    $scope.setDate = function(startDate, endDate) {
        $rootScope.startDate = $scope.startDateL;
        $rootScope.endDate = $scope.endDateL;

        var stDate = $filter('date')($rootScope.startDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');
        var enDate = $filter('date')($rootScope.endDate,'yyyy-MM-dd');

        console.log(stDate);
        console.log(enDate);

        datePickerFactory.save({sDate: stDate, eDate: enDate}, function(){
        })

        localStorage.setItem('chosenStartDate', JSON.stringify($rootScope.startDate));
        localStorage.setItem('chosenEndDate', JSON.stringify($rootScope.endDate));
        $rootScope.$broadcast("dateWasChosen");
        $mdDialog.hide();

    }

}
```

Now, what i want to do is to set a current date on my date field in my modal so that I have a default date when i open my modal.Is there a function that can set the current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a date object in your controller.

```
$scope.startDateL = new Date();
$scope.endDateL  = new Date();
```